# VSTS Xamarin UWP Build: Cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime

Tags: xamarin, build, uwp, azure-devops

We are trying to make a build on TFS server for Xamarin solution.

However we are getting following Error "**WMC1006: Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0**"

We are struggling for 2 weeks already and loosing hope... :(
Is here any good soul who has any clue how to fix it?

Here are our settings and build log: 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: According to your MSbuild task configuration and the log of this task, you specified the MSbuild version as 15.0 in task. But in fact, while the compile, it was using MSbuild 14.0. This should the caused reason. Does your TFS server has VS2017? Please try with specify MSbuild 14.0 to build your project.

Comment: Don't use this version of "Nuge installer", this doesn't use the nuget-version installed by the nuget-installer and doesn't provide the versions itself you need (you need 4.1 or later when working with uwp and its dependencies)

Comment: select a higher version of nuget in the nuget-installer task, anything higher then 4.1

Comment: and disable the nuget-restore-option on your vs-task

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT no thats not the build but a nuget-commandline that runs inside this task. that's the nuget-restore option from the vs-task that is using an older version of nuget. this option should be disabled anyway... the compile uses msbuild-15